# Is it acceptable to repeatedly add the pronoun "others" + adjective, without a verb, when describing multiple kinds of elements?

Tags: adjectives

I'm not an english native speaker and I had a doubt regarding the usage of the pronoun "others" + an adjective (without the verb) when describing multiple types of a given thing.

For example:

> Other important episodes exist in my life: some of them are fun, **others**
>   interesting, **others** plain ridiculous, **others** straightforward epic.

In spanish it would be fine, as it is understood that there's an omission of the verb ("are"), and you keep going with the additions.

Would it be fine in english as well?

Many thanks for your help,

Comment: Avoid asking for help writing (or proofreading). “How should I write this?”, “is this correct?”, and “which is correct?” questions are out of scope and your question may be removed. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. If there is an unstated specific concern, such as “What does (word) mean in context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in context?” ask that question instead. Also check out “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)”

Comment: Can you say specifically why you worry that using the word "others" repeatedly would violate a grammar rule? What grammar rule?

Comment: Well I'm not a native speaker of english so I had that doubt. Maybe it didn't sound correct to some people, or it was an unusual resource, and I wanted to hear someone else's thoughts about it. But it looks like it's acceptable after your comment, so thank you.

Comment: The usual sequence is: some, others, still others. If more than three groups, look for another construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Other** can be used ... as a **pronoun** ... in the plural without 'the':
>
> *Some systems are better than others.
>
> The plural form **others** without 'the' is the plural of the pronoun **another**.
>
> [- MACMILLAN DICTIONARY](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/other_1)

(Please excuse the all-caps in the attribution - that's how the dictionary presents its name).

Although the dictionary doesn't say it, *others* and *another* tend to be used only once per list. In the context you mention, the word *others* has an air of finality about it. If you need to specify 'more' others, it's better to keep using *some*, leaving *others* for the last group:

- some of them are fun, some interesting, some plain ridiculous, others [simply] epic.

Comment: Thank you, that was a spot on and complete answer! Cheers,